# Media Query "Screen" CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to set a media query on my css but it dosen't work

```
#calc{
width: 325px;
height: auto;
margin: 100px auto;
padding: 20px 20px 9px;
/*background: linear-gradient(#9dd2ea, #8bc);*/
background-image: url('http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/christmas-seamless-pattern-big-small-snowflakes-white-cyan-background-34953788.jpg');
border-radius: 15px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px #009de4;
}
```

heres the css for the media query

```
@media screen and (min-height: 500px) {
#calc
{
            /*margin-top: 0; or margin: 0 auto;*/
    margin-top: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have the media query below the other styles?

Comment: The media query is at the bottom of the CSS code.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `margin-top`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:767px) {
  #calc{margin-top: 0;}
}
```

Use this code for responsive device . replace according to condition